# CSS arrow on an image (without using borders)

Tags: css, mask, css-shapes, pseudo-element

I'm trying to figure out a way to use attach an arrow to the bottom of a masthead image, [like this](http://d.pr/i/hg6q). I've seen a number of methods on how to create arrows with CSS3, but I've found they almost always use the border property to achieve it. Usually something like this:

```
#demo {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   position: relative;
   border: 4px solid #333;
 }

#demo:after {
   border-width: 9px;
   border-left-color: #ccc;
   top: 15px;
 }
```

I'm trying to find a way to create that sort of mask shape without any images other than the main art. Has anyone achieved this? If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There isn't going to be an easy way to do this... might just be easier to address it with an image. If you got that example off a site, i could look at their source and tell you what they did.

Comment: Do I understand you properly? You want to add an arrow using css3 but without using border property or additional images.

Comment: Yeah, basically i can't use a border because that would make the arrow a solid color. I'd also rather not use another image because my masthead (full width) resizes with the window, and if it gets enlarged the arrow will become pixelated.. i'd like to keep it crisp, so i was wondering if it was possible to add an arrow-shaped mask with CSS3.

Comment: You could explore using an SVG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for an arrow that resizes with the image, then yes, it can be done.

## [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/full/opbCI)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='head'></div>
<div class='arrow'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.head {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  /* take into account ratio of the image but with 20% less for the height */
  padding: 12.5% 30%;
  background: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.arrow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: -4.9% auto;
  padding: 4.42%; /* 25% of head's padding * sqrt(2) */
  width: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: red;
}
.arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: -70.71%; /* half of the width or height */
  width: 141.42%; height: 141.42%; /* sqrt(2)*141.42% */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: url(background.jpg) 50% 100%;
  background-size: 480% 250%; /* take into account ratio of the image */
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: I see nothing but a white screen in the demo; someone confirm?

Comment: yea, demo is empty